# Access Sorting by Name

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a query to show the top students in each test. Is there a way to do it in one single query where the grades are sorted but the name of the student appears and I don't have to create separate queries? The Student has test from when they're in first to High School for example so it's a bit overwhelming for me to sort every test individually. I would appreciate any help. (I'm sorting an ancient grade book, scanned).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all the information is coming from the same table, creat a query from that table and plug in the information i.e. Students name, grade, etc. under the grade sort it by ascending. If you're wanting to limit the results to say the top ten, then in the SQL view after SELECT you'd put TOP 10.